# Would it be tax efficient to create a company to invest though personally

Tags: united-kingdom, private-company

A question, say I have 100k in savings and I pay higher rate tax.

In peer to peer saving I could get 8% and there get interest for 8k. And be liable for 3000 tax. So get 5k out.
End with 100k savings and 5k in my bank.

Could I create a company, file simple accounts and do the following. 
100k in company make 8k which I think it's under the 10k corp tax limit, pay myself 5k in dividend, and leave the 3k in the company.

So end up with 103 in the company and 5k in my bank.

The are some payment to accountants and for filling out accounts, but is the theory sound ????

Comment: You pay personal income tax on any money you receive from the company.

Comment: @jim garrison, I don't believe that to be the case, it's a well known tactic for self employed people to pay them selves very little PAYE income and PSU the rest as divided as it's tax efficient. Or do you have some documentation to back up your claim, by the way this is in the UK

Comment: Not sure about the UK, but in the US this wouldn't help you because you would pay tax on the 5K, and also either you or the company would pay tax on the remaining 3K depending on what type of company it is. I'd be surprised if the UK allowed this because if so everyone could just create a separate company for every 10K in revenue they receive.